# How to detect the outgoing Call duration for the last outgoing call?

Tags: java, android

I done the code for viewing the outgoing call details from the  call log in that how can i get the last outgoing call duration.I tried it many times but problem was not solved. In the below code i got the outgoing call details but the required output is to get the 
outgoing call duration for last outgoing call.Please help me to solve this...

```
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");
    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    sb.append("Call Details :");
    while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
        String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
        String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
        String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
        Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
        String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
        String dir = null;
        int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);


        switch (dircode) {
            case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                dir = "OUTGOING";
                sb.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + phNumber + " \nCall Type:--- " + dir + " \nCall Date:--- " + callDayTime + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + callDuration);
                sb.append("\n----------------------------------");
                textView.setText(sb);
                break;

            case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                dir = "INCOMING";

                break;

            case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                dir = "MISSED";
                break;
        }
    }

    managedCursor.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the logic, you need to store the last position when switch statement for outgoing gets true then retrieve that position and move the cursor ant get the required data as mentioned below code in updated code

```
 StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");
            int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
            int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
            int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
            int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
            sb.append("Call Details :");
            int currentCount =0, lastPosition =0;
            while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
                currentCount++;
                String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
                String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
                String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
                Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
                String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
                String dir = null;
                int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);


                switch (dircode) {
                    case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                        lastPosition = currentCount;
                        dir = "OUTGOING";
                        sb.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + phNumber + " \nCall Type:--- " + dir + " \nCall Date:--- " + callDayTime + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + callDuration);
                        sb.append("\n----------------------------------");
                        Log.e("test", sb.toString());
                        //textView.setText(sb);
                        break;

                    case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                        dir = "INCOMING";

                        break;

                    case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                        dir = "MISSED";
                        break;
                }
            }

            lastPosition--;
            managedCursor.moveToPosition(lastPosition);
            int requiredNumber = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
            String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(requiredNumber);
            Log.e("last position number ", phNumber);
            managedCursor.close();
```

Comment: In the above code i got only last outgoing call number ,how can i get the last call outgoing duration in that. @Abdul Waheed

Comment: welcome...for duration you need get duration column as it has already available in your code....call number was just a demo for retrieval